# Find Hostname by having IP-Address

Tags: windows, ip, command-line-interface, hostname, host

Is there a way to find out hostnames only by having the IP's of the hosts, while only using Windows' command line (cmd)?

Answer (score 5):

Two methods:

1. Ping -a `ip address`
2. nslookup `ip address` (This will only work if you have an rDNS zone setup).

Comment: I'd add a third, `nbtstat -A IpAddress`. When there is no DNS, there might still be NetBIOS.

Answer (score 2):

`ping -a` performs a reverse lookup in Windows parlance.

(This is not a guaranteed method since it relies on the likelihood of DNS being set up properly which is fairly unlikely. And by 'unlikely' I mean it's not.)